# Excel-VBA get number from letter equivalent entry in a textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form that asks for a column reference to be entered into a TextBox. I am trying to make it so that the number replaces the letter in the code. I am using the Cells(a,b) format to do this. Which is why I need the number to replace the letter.

```
Worksheets("AIO").Cells(X, TextBox3).Value = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, TextBox4).Value
```

Hence in the previous code when: x=2, TextBox3.Value=A, y=4, and TextBox4.Value=AA

The code will work as

```
Worksheets("AIO").Cells(2, 1).Value = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(4, 27).Value
```

The only thing I can think of making is a huge if statement were I code something similar like this:

```
If textbox3.value ="A" then
textbox3.value=1
elseif textbox3.value=E then
textbox3.value=5
.......
.......
textbox3.value=AD then
textbox3.value=30

End If
```

Comment: I had something simular and did a `select case` function for this. There must be something easier but I didnt have time to work it out or search for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it uncomplicated, `.Cells` can use the column string instead of number

```
Sub test()
    'From sheet module
    Debug.Print Me.Cells(1, 1).Address 'prints $A$1
    Debug.Print Me.Cells(1, "A").Address 'also prints $A$1 
End Sub
```

You might have to validate that it's a valid column ID but you probably need to do that even converting it to a number.

Comment: How would  I incorpate the textbox value?

Comment: I tried the following: Cells(1,"Textbox3.value") and Cells(1,"Textbox") and neither were read correctly.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes.  `Cells(1, Textbox3.value)` or assign `Textbox3.value` to a variable to validate the entry.  The way you have it written you're looking for a column literally called "Textbox3.value"

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this works. I could have sworn I tried that but apparently I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

On way to get a **column number** from a **character string:**

```
Sub ColumnNumber()
  Dim s As String
  Dim L As Long
  s = "AB"
  L = Cells(1, s).Column
  MsgBox L
End Sub
```